# Override onepage/link.phtml

Tags: magento2.2

we are trying to override the cart "go to checkout" button in a custom module, but can't get it working state. (CE 2.2.6)

I am using `view/layout/checkout_cart_index.xml` with the following content

```
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceContainer name="content">
            <referenceBlock name="checkout.cart.methods.onepage.bottom" template="Namespace_Module::onepage/link.phtml" />
        </referenceContainer>
    </body>
</page>
```

And copied the original content to `templates/onepage/link.phtml`

So far so good, it doesn't work (checked with template hints and added a marker to `link.phtml`)

Any ideas would be helpful.

**Cheers
Jan**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Try This :-**

```
<referenceBlock name="checkout.cart.methods.onepage.bottom">
   <action method="setTemplate">
       <argument name="template" xsi:type="string">Namespace_Module::onepage/link.phtml</argument>
   </action>
</referenceBlock>
```

Comment: Hey Ronak, 

sadly the result is the same, doesn't work.
I also tried to use the alias in the outer referenceContainer ("methods").

Confused!

Comment: not working ?????

Comment: See above @Ronak Rathod. Thanks!

Comment: check my updated answer

Comment: Your updated solution works! Many many thanks - why do you need to use the setTemplate method, it's unclear to me!

Comment: because you need to overwrite the template so

Comment: Can you please link the related documentation? THX

Comment: https://www.classyllama.com/blog/template-override-m2  for Override a Template and approve the answer

Comment: Good docu! According to it the node has changed from setTemplate method to <arguments>, so I will give this a try also.

Comment: yes ... This article will cover which methods for overriding a template are appropriate for a variety of cases and when you should consider pursuing an alternative to a template override.

Comment: Seems to be related to 2.3, have to read the github issue thread...In conclusion, doesn't work with Ce 2.2.6

<referenceBlock name="checkout.cart.methods.onepage.bottom">
            <arguments>
                <argument name="template" xsi:type="string">Namespace_Module::onepage/link.phtml</argument>
            </arguments>
        </referenceBlock>